# Upper bound for linear function

Tags: functions, computer-science, asymptotics

> What may be more surprising is that when $a>0$, any *linear* function $an +b$ is $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ which is easily verified by taking $c = a + |b|$  and $n_o = \max (\frac{-b}{a}, 1)$.

$$an + b < cn^2,n>n_o$$
$$\frac{a}{n} + \frac{b}{n^2} < c, n>n_o$$
$$\implies c = a + |b|, n > 1$$

Why does the excerpt use $n_o = \max (\frac{-b}{a}, 1)$ instead of $n_o = 1$? Thanks for the help.

Comment: Could write for $n \ge 1$: $a n + b \le (a + b) n \le \lvert a + b \lvert n^2$, and you are absolutely right. The negative sign is wrong anyway (graph a few of the curves).

Comment: In the $\implies$ it is used that $b/n^2<b$ if $n>1$, but this holds only if $b$ is **positive**. I guess the other one is for $b<0$.